# Blob Service REST API - Put Blob returning 403 Forbidden when x-ms-blob-content-type is set

Tags: api, rest, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've successfully been able to create Blobs in my container, but when I try to set the x-ms-blob-content-type header, no Blob is created and I get a 403 error. Here is my code:

```
    var authorizationHeader = CreateAuthorizationHeader(stringToSign);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(blobEndpoint + urlPath);
    request.Method = requestMethod;
    request.Headers["x-ms-blob-type"] = blobType;            
    request.Headers["x-ms-date"] = dateInRfc1123Format;
    request.Headers["x-ms-version"] = storageServiceVersion;
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = authorizationHeader;
    request.ContentLength = blobLength;            

    try
    {
        using (Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            requestStream.Write(blobContent, 0, blobLength);
        }

        using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            var eTag = response.Headers["ETag"];
        }
    }
```

But whenever I try to add either of these lines, I get a 403:

```
request.Headers["x-ms-blob-content-type"] = "image/jpeg";
//or
request.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```

Have any of you encountered this? Appreciate any feedback, thanks!

**UPDATE:** adding the stringToSign code below.

```
var canonicalizedHeaders = String.Format(
    "x-ms-blob-type:{0}\nx-ms-date:{1}\nx-ms-version:{2}",
    blobType,
    dateInRfc1123Format,
    storageServiceVersion);
var canonicalizedResource = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", account, urlPath);
var stringToSign = String.Format(
    "{0}\n\n\n{1}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{2}\n{3}",
    requestMethod,
    blobLength,
    canonicalizedHeaders,
    canonicalizedResource);
```

Comment: Can you share the code to create `stringToSign` variable?

Comment: @GauravMantri added it in. i've also tried to add the x-ms-blob-content-type onto the canonicalizedHeaders but still keep getting a 403.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add `x-ms-blob-content-type` in both `canonicalizedHeaders` and in `request headers`? When adding it to `canonicalizedHeaders`, please make sure that this would be the first entry as the headers need to be sorted. I took your code and added the header and it worked perfectly fine. Here's my code:

```
    private static async Task UploadBlob()
    {
        var blobType = "BlockBlob";
        var dateInRfc1123Format = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
        var storageServiceVersion = "2014-02-14";
        var blobContentType = "image/png";
        var canonicalizedHeaders = String.Format("x-ms-blob-content-type:{0}\nx-ms-blob-type:{1}\nx-ms-date:{2}\nx-ms-version:{3}", blobContentType, blobType, dateInRfc1123Format, storageServiceVersion);
        var urlPath = "test-test/AlarmClock1.png";
        var canonicalizedResource = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", accountName, urlPath);
        var requestMethod = "PUT";
        var fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\images\images\AlarmClock1.png");
        var blobLength = fileContents.Length;
        var stringToSign = String.Format("{0}\n\n\n{1}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{2}\n{3}", requestMethod, blobLength, canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource);
        var authorizationHeader = SignThis(stringToSign);
        var blobEndpoint = "https://myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(blobEndpoint + urlPath);
        request.Method = requestMethod;
        request.Headers["x-ms-blob-content-type"] = blobContentType;
        request.Headers["x-ms-blob-type"] = blobType;            
        request.Headers["x-ms-date"] = dateInRfc1123Format;
        request.Headers["x-ms-version"] = storageServiceVersion;
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = authorizationHeader;
        request.ContentLength = blobLength;   
        try
        {
            using (Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
            {
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, blobLength);
            }

            using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                var eTag = response.Headers["ETag"];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, really appreciate your help and reply, thank you. I've added it as mentioned in my comment above, but not in the order you have suggested (it being first). I will try it and will mark your answer as correct if I get it sorted.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. So it is because of the order of the canonicalized headers. Missed this part in the documentation, "Sort the headers lexicographically by header name, in ascending order."